# How to ignore case when using filters with the mongo driver in dot net core with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

I have an aggregates pipeline query as below:

```
string [] sids   = { array of Student ids here };
string deptName = "math";
var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$match",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {"studentid", new BsonDocument("$in",BsonArray.Create(sids))},
                {"dept",BsonRegularExpression.Create(new Regex( dept, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))}
            }
        ),
            new BsonDocument("$sort",new BsonDocument("CardSwipeTimestamp", -1)),
                               
            new BsonDocument("$group",
                new BsonDocument{
                        { "_id",
                            new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "studentid","$studentid" },
                                { "dept","$dept"}
                            }
                        },
                        { "Status",new BsonDocument("$first", "$Status")},
                        { "CardSwipeTimestamp",new BsonDocument("$first", "$CardSwipeTimestamp")}
                    }
                ),
       new BsonDocument("$project",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", 0 },
                { "studentid", "$_id.studentid" },
                { "dept", "$_id.dept" },
                { "Status", "$Status" },
                { "CardSwipeTimestamp", "$CardSwipeTimestamp" }
            }
        ),
         new BsonDocument("$skip",0),
         new BsonDocument("$limit",3),
    };

collectionName.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList()
```

These only returns a value if the department passed in matches the case of what is stored in the collection.

How to ignore the case of the incoming parameter when doing a search using the above query?

Comment: If you want to search with case insensitive, then you need to change the value to regex pattern. See [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the--in-operator-with-a-regular-expression) and [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). But doubt that it will affect the index performance.

Comment: I looked at that but was not able to create the query from that. Do you have an example? I have modified my code above and that doesn't work as well.

Comment: [Sample Data](https://imgur.com/v9c6gPJ), [Sample Code](https://imgur.com/3J2IyCj), [Result](https://imgur.com/undefined). I test with `$match` stage with $regex, it works. Maybe you need try to run the MongoDB query (based on your C# query) in MongoDB compass to verify that the query is correct.

Comment: You can also look for [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/). But to use this, you need `$expr` too. For example: `{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$studentid", []], $eq: [ {$toLower: "$dept"}, {$toLower: /* dept value */} ] } }`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the two sides of the match expression to lowercase with [ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-6.0)

```
ToLower(left operand).equal(ToLower(right operand))  //so we can ignore case.
```